# In ProviderRepository.php line 206: Class "Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider"

Tags: php, laravel-10

I am trying to  publish image intervention but I get this kind error in terminal and browser,
[this display of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLdH8.png)

I have tryed to install image intervention including doing all configuration but installation  was successful I add Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class and $aliases  'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class in app.php but the problem arise when I try to publish package,[APP.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pFhX.png),my controller [my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iLAk.png)  and my composer .json [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Imj.png)

Comment: any one to answer this question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Have you run `composer install` and `composer dumpautoload`? Does `vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageServiceProvider.php` exist?

Comment: I have run composer install but still the error appear

Answer (score 0):

I have a laravel 10 installation and i tried to install according to the instructions to recreate the problem and try to find a resolution:
[image intervention install for laravel](https://image.intervention.io/v2/introduction/installation#integration-in-laravel)

problem 1:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

does not exist in vendor folder

problem 2:

```
Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

does not exist in vendor folder for aliasing

i did:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

I cannot explain it but for me it is impossible to install it when i follow the instructions. I checked out the vendor folder and there is no service provider file. There is also no facades folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my past question it can be seen that I install Intervention Image v3 in Laravel, but that's why the bugs exist.

**So the best solution is to uninstall.**

1. Using this command: `composer remove intervention/image` - it will uninstall v3.
2. Comment `use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;`.
3. Use this command to install: `composer require "intervention/image=~2.0"`
4. Uncomment `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class`.
5. Make sure your aliases contain this code: `'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class`.
6. Publish Intervention Image - use this command: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravelRecent"`
7. Note all of this is done in `app.php`.
8. Problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**FOLLOW THIS STEP CAREFUL BUT MAKE SURE YOU HAVE INSTALL COMPOSER `composer install or composer update` THEN PROCEED**

1.**comment this line in app.php if are there in your code, if are not there proceed with next step**

Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class

2.**remove composer use this code.**

```
command composer remove
```

3.**install image intervention used this code**

```
composer require "intervention/image=~2.0"
```

4.**uncomment this line of code if are present in app.php if are not there update them**
*In the $providers array add the service providers for this package*.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

*Add the facade 'of this package to the*

```
$aliases array. Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

5.**Publish configuration in Laravel**.

```
php artisan vendor: publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravelRecent"
```

6.**problem solved if not solved let me know**